# Sharing VPN access to my LAN - security concern

Tags: security, vpn

I recently subscribed to a VPN service (Vpnsecure.me) and I have been thinking to share it to my all LAN via my synology NAS or my raspberry PI. Before configuring my devices, I would like to know how my all LAN would be exposed. Is there any risk ? In case of, do you have any advice to secure my LAN ?

Any help would be appreciated

Best regards,

Gwenaeld

Answer (score 0):

I will answer in general, because your question in general. You have few different options:

1. You can use your router (not all routers can do this job)

   - add vpn connection
   - add routing through vpn
2. Install on raspberry pi debian based system.

   - connect VPN on raspberry pi
   - make nat (forwarding) through VPN
   - change getway/routes on your end point systems to use raspberry pi as gateway.
3. You can try Install VPN on your synology but it will be a little bit difficult or impossible. But it will be the same as second variant.

**VPN is too heavy for raspberry/synology and forward. You will have small internet speed.**